# ECS agent can not successfully pull image from ECR when host can

Tags: docker, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr, docker-pull

Saw relevant answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52934781/15648070) but has both already configured

Getting `STOPPED (CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daem)`

ECR is in `Account A` and ECS cluster in on `Account B`

Have this policy on the ECR repository in `Account A` (cross-organization sharing)

```
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowPull",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": [
        "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
        "ecr:BatchGetImage",
        "ecr:DescribeImages",
        "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
          "aws:PrincipalOrgPaths": "o-x/*"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When running manually on the Instance `aws ecr login Account-A` + `docker pull Account-A.xxx` it works great.

Any idea why the ECS agent can't do it himself ?

ECS task role & task execution role uses this IAM role :

```
SecretsManagerReadWrite    
AmazonSQSFullAccess    
AmazonS3ReadOnlyAccess    
AmazonECS_FullAccess    
AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy
AmazonMSKReadOnlyAccess
```

EC2 Instance role :

```
AmazonSSMManagedInstanceCore
CloudWatchLogsFullAccess
AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role
```

Comment: I know this answer specifically mentions Fargate instead of EC2, but I believe the answer is the same for ECS running on either Fargate or EC2: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52934781/13070

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, as you can see I have both configured (Acc A repository level policy and the needed permissions on Acc B ECS task role)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going to need to make it explicit in the [ECS container instance IAM role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/instance_IAM_role.html) that you are giving permission to Account B to get containers from Account A.

In cross account access you have to setup permissions on each side. Account A has to allow access to get the containers (the policy you specified in your question accounts for that). Account B has to give explicit permissions to services through roles and role profiles to access resources in other accounts. I think that is what you are missing.

Another [walk through in resolving this is available here](https://medium.com/miq-tech-and-analytics/cross-account-how-to-access-aws-container-registry-service-from-another-aws-account-using-iam-b372796ede14), which may help you think through this further.